# What can possibly cause these random shutdowns?

Tags: laptop, shutdown, dell-inspiron

My Dell Inspiron N411Z laptop has random shutdown problems.

I'm guessing this is a hardware problem, but I don't know, what exactly can cause these shutdowns... Yes, I've thought about an overheating issue, and actually, this machine had fan problems a couple of months ago. But now the fan is replaced and there is absolutely no heating issue.

When I had the random shutdowns, I did not measure more than 65°C, but since these shutdown usually occur a few minutes after I turn on the device, so about 44-45°C is a normal temperature when the shutdowns happen.

The motherboard triggers an emergency shutdown when one of the cores reach 105°C so I'm pretty sure it's not the heat, unless it goes up about 50°C in less than a second, which doesn't seem legit. Also, I even had an unwanted shutdown in sleeping mode.

These shutdowns usually occur when I'm using it on my lap instead of on a flat surface.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the soldering of the power connector on your motherboard that got loose, hence the random shutdowns.